# Powershell search and replace string with unknown ending

Tags: powershell

I want to replace 03 01 2018 with a different date. 
With the following or something better:

————

```
$M = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your MM'

$D = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the DD'

$Y = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your YY'

(Get-Content C:\Users\Desktop\file.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "DOB=                ", "MM DD YY" } | Set-Content C:\Users\Desktop\file.txt
```

————

I don’t know how to search for a random date. Also DOB= ** ** ** is never in the same line number.

————

File.txt Ex:

```
FLOPPY=TRUE

CLOSETIME=0

OPENTIME=0400

EVENTTIME=0

DOB=03 01 2018         (I don’t know the date and it not base on the system date)
```

xxxxxxxx=00 00 0000

xxxxxxxx=00 00 0000

```
Variable 1

Variable 2

Variable 3

....
```

——————

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using this:

```
(Get-Content C:\Users\Desktop\file.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "\b(DOB=\d{2} \d{2} \d{4})\b", "MM DD YY" } | Set-Content C:\Users\Desktop\file.txt
```

Comment: It works but one little issue.  The flie as other areas like 00 00 0000.                                           FLOPPY=TRUE
CLOSETIME=0
OPENTIME=0400
EVENTTIME=0
DOB=03 14 2018
xxxxxxxx=00 00 0000
xxxxxxxx=00 00 0000

Comment: It replaces all other areas with 00 00 0000

Comment: Use `\b(DOB=\d{2} \d{2} \d{4})\b` to specifically find "DOB=xx xx xxxx" pattern.

Comment: $M = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your MM'
$D = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the DD'
$Y = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your YYYY'

(Get-Content C:\Users\Desktop\file.txt) | ForEach-Object { 
$_ -replace "\b(DOB=\d{2} \d{2} \d{4})\b", "DOB=$M $D $Y" 
   } | Set-Content C:\Users\Desktop\file.txt

Comment: Accept the answer if it works for you :).